# Cannot Click button on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any reason why the prompt will not appear when clicking the bottom on my web page? The other buttons works on my web page fine but the "create room" button will not work and I am not sure why.

Any Ideas?

```
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}
<h2>General Chat</h2>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="upper-wrapper">
        <div id="available-rooms-dialog">
            <h4>Available Rooms</h4>
            <input type="button" onclick="s = prompt('Enter a new Room Name', 'Name');" id=" createroom" value="Create Room" />
        </div>
        <div id="discussion-dialog">
            <textarea rows="30" cols="50" id="discussion"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="message-dialog">
        <textarea rows="3" id="message">Type your message</textarea>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Post" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <input type="checkbox" id="enter-sends-message"/>
        Enter sends message
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var json;


    $(function () {



        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            // Add the message to the page.

            //TODO: Add Record to Server
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "Post",
                url: "@Url.Action("AddMessage", "Home")",
                data: { messageCont: message.toString() },
                success: function (data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        //access with data[i].modelattribute
                    }
                }
            });

            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "Get",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetMessages", "Home")",
                success: function (data) {
                    json = data;
                    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        //access with data[i].modelattribute
                        $('#discussion').append(htmlEncode(obj[i].Author) + " : " + htmlEncode(obj[i].Message) + "\r\n");
                    }
                }
            });

        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });

    // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;

    }

</script>

}
```

Comment: All seems to working fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/59KPQ/

Comment: it's working. check other javascript error in your page

Comment: I have updated the code to show all javascript as well

Comment: Which browser are you using? Is there any extension which adds javascript to a webpage. Most of them does, try checking by disabling all extensions.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome. I tried disabling all the extensions and it is still not working. The code doesnt even work in IE which is strange